# Connecting USB Devices to Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

From what I know, android emulator cannot listen to USB or any other devices of Hosting machine, and thus I have a question: Is there any way to emulate USB connections (or any other device connection like headphones or microphone) on an Emulator? Maybe through adb or emulator command tools? Or maybe there is a way to have the emulator see devices connected to the host (PC, Windows OS)?

My application has an option menu where all connected audio devices are listed, and the user can choose from this list. However, for Android TV I'm using an emulator and I can't connect new devices to test it out.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: look into using virtualbox with android, it might work

Answer (score 6):

Do you use emulator on Ubuntu? If yes, try:

1. list the usb device use lsusb, e.g. for my logictech wireless
   keyboard and mouse dongle

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

2. start the emulator

```
sudo ./emulator @Pixel_XL_API_Q -kernel /home/robot/Android/goldfish/arch/x86/boot/bzImage  -qemu -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=23
```

3. now you can switch the keyboard and mouse to the emulator

That works for me

https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest

will give you some infos.

Comment: This answer was a good start to me, but I also had to build my own kernel to get additional drivers and enable usb android USB API. https://gist.github.com/Alabate/200f021e644baed84993dd6109811ba2

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am using the standard Android emulator. If I specify the args, -qemu -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=4617,productid=21441 (my device) I get the error libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]

Comment: Is it possible to do this on MacOs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtualbox with an android image.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: You need to download and install oracle virtualbox. Then download Android x86 image and mount it into virtualbox. To access usb from virtualbox Android you need to go to  VirtualBox->Devices->USB settings.